# How to position multiple text fields in same line using Struts 2 without using theme="simple"?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, struts2

I want to design a webpage that display the user id and password in same line using Struts 2.

**How to manage it without using `theme='simple'`**?

```jsp
 <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><html>
<head>      

</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="Register.action">

        <s:textfield name="uid" label="User Name"/>
        <s:password name="pass" label="Password"/>
    </s:form>
</div>
```

Source Code of the above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="Register" action="Register.action" method="post">
        <table class="wwFormTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="tdLabel">
                    <label for="Register_uid" class="label">User Name:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="uid" value="" id="Register_uid"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdLabel">
                    <label for="Register_pass" class="label">Password:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="Register_pass"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default Struts2 is using `xhtml` theme, that wraps input fields with the table layout. A table layout utilizes unique positioning of its elements, using rows and columns. You can't display two rows on the same line.

On the other hand there's a theme [`css_xhtml`](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/css-xhtml-theme.html) that is using

> Standard two-column CSS-based layout, using  for the HTML Struts Tags (form, textfield, select, etc)

you can change the style of elements to display inline. If `div`s are generated for textfilds them you can use a style `dysplay: inline-block`

> ## The inline-block Value
>
>
>   It has been possible for a long time to create a grid of boxes that fills the browser width and wraps nicely (when the browser is
>   resized), by using the `float` property.
>
> However, the `inline-block` value of the `display` property makes this
>   even easier.
>
> inline-block elements are like inline elements but they can have a
>   width and a height.

**The code:**

```jsp
<style>
.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style> 

<s:form action="Register.action" theme="css_xhtml">

    <s:textfield name="uid" label="User Name" cssClass="floating-box"/>
    <s:password name="pass" label="Password" cssClass="floating-box"/>

</s:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your generated HTML, you can apply the CSS rule `display:inline-block;` to the `<tr>` of your table:

```css
input{width:100px;} /* needed only to fit in the "Run code snippet" box */

.wwFormTable tr {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table class="wwFormTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label for="Register_uid" class="label">User Name:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="uid" value="" id="Register_uid" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label for="Register_pass" class="label">Password:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="Register_pass" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That said, I have the sensation that you might not be aware of the fact that you can use the `simple` theme on a single element

```xml
<s:form action="Register.action">
    <s:textfield name="uid"  label="User Name" theme="simple" />
    <s:password  name="pass" label="Password"  theme="simple" />
</s:form>
```

or on a single form

```xml
<s:form action="Register.action" theme="simple">
    <s:textfield name="uid"  label="User Name" />
    <s:password  name="pass" label="Password"  />
</s:form>
```

without dropping the usage of the `XHTML` theme on the whole application.